# Let $G$ be a finite group. Show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ (symmetric group).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am solving a geometry exercise in which I have to proof the following:

Let $G$ be a finite group with $n=\vert G \vert$ elements. Show that $G$ is isomorph to a subset of $S_n$ (symmertric group).

**Problem:** Since we only had 4 geometry lectures we have not covered a lot. We get an exercise sheet every 2nd week and have lectures every week. We have not covered cayley's theorem yet. Is this theorem necessary to solve the exercise? I looked up cayley's theorem and its proof in *M.Artin - Algebra* and *Fraleigh's First Course in Abstract Algebra*. I tried it on my own but I would be glad if you could correct or enhance my 'proof'.

**My Attempt**: 
Let $|G|=n$ . We want $|G|$ to me isomorph to $S_n$. So we can number the elements of $G$:

$ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & \ldots & n\\ a_1 & a_2 & \ldots & a_n \end{array}  $

we can now choose $x\in G$ and do a left multiplication, which leads to the following

$\Rightarrow$

$ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & \ldots & n\\ x \cdot a_1 & x \cdot a_2 & \ldots &  x \cdot a_n \end{array}  $

so we can say therefore the elements will be newly arranged in $G$ after the multiplication and because we numbered the elements of $G$ we can 'look up' where they have been before. That actually means:

$x \cdot a_i = a_j$ so therefore x sends element $a$ from place $i$ to place $j$ (permutation). So we define the following definition:

$\lambda_x=\begin{cases} \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \rightarrow \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \\ \lambda_x(i) \quad \qquad \mapsto \ j \end{cases}$

so therefore we can write:

$ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 2 & \ldots & n\\ a_{\lambda_x(1)} & a_{\lambda_x(2)} & \ldots & a_{\lambda_x(n)} \end{array}  $

now we can state a new function:

$\phi=\begin{cases} G \quad \rightarrow \quad S_n \\ \phi(\lambda(x)) \mapsto \lambda_x \end{cases}$

which basically means: we link the permutation that the left multiplication by x does to its x. Now we have to proof the isomorphism between $G$ and $S_n$ therefore it needs to be bijective and homomorphic. Well $\phi$ needs to be a group homomorphism and bijective which means:

*homomorphism:*

Let $\lambda(i),\lambda(j) \in G$ , $(G, \star)$ and $(S_n, *)$ be the two groups then:

$\phi(\lambda(i) \star \lambda(j))= \phi(\lambda(i)) * \phi(\lambda(j)) = \lambda_i * \lambda_j$

*bijective:*

injective: $\forall \lambda(i),\lambda(j) \in G\ , \ \phi(\lambda(i)) = \phi(\lambda(j)) \Rightarrow \lambda_i=\lambda_j$
surjective: $ \forall \lambda_x \in S_n \ , \ \exists \lambda(x) \in G : \phi(\lambda(x)) = \lambda_x \qquad  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \Box$

Comment: It is not true that $G$ will be isomorph to $S_n$. It will be isomorph to a subgroup of $S_{n!}$.

Comment: thank you for the remark. I meant that in my 'proof' n should be a number such as 23.

Comment: You are on the right track, except that you need only show the two poroperties *homomorphism* and *injective* (you need not and in general cannot show surjectivity as per Denis's comment)

Comment: Do not enumerate $G$, this makes the whole proof obscure and complicated. If $G$ is any (!) group with underlying set $|G|$, then one writes down a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Sym}(|G|)$, which is injective.

Comment: yes I thought that this is not sufficient. I tried to use somehow the elements of $G$ and $S_n$ but I don't know how to proof the two properties.

Comment: @@Martin But ultimately we need permutations of the set $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ that is used in the very definition of $S_n$. So at some point ew do need a bijection of the underlying set with this set integers. Of course any bijection between sets induces an isomorpphism of the Sym's ...

Comment: @Denis i am sorry i did not see the $S_n!$ but anyhow i don't see how i should continue or even start then.

Comment: @Denis Oh yes, we *can* take $n=|G|$ in $S_n$ (and the OP successfully does, just doesn't know how to show he succeeded)

Comment: Yes sorry $S_n$ has the cardinality $n!$ of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following mark Brandenburg's comment, I suggest to first note the following:

> If $A,B$ are two sets and $f\colon A\to B$ is a bijection (so $f^{-1}$ exists), then we obtain a group isomorphism $\phi_f\colon \operatorname{Sym}(A)\to \operatorname{Sym}(B)$ by letting $\phi_f(\sigma)=f\circ \sigma\circ f^{-1}$ for each $\sigma\in \operatorname{Sym}(A)$.

To see that $\phi_f$ is a *homomorphism* note that $$\phi_f(\sigma)\phi_f(\tau)=f\circ \sigma\circ f^{-1}\circ f\circ \tau\circ f^{-1}=f\circ \sigma\circ \tau\circ f^{-1}=\phi_f(\sigma\tau);$$ to see that $\phi_f$ is an *isomorphism* note that we can explicitly name the inverse homomoprhism $\operatorname{Sym}(B)\to\operatorname{Sym}(A)$, namely we have $(\phi_f)^{-1}=\phi_{f^{-1}}$: $$\phi_{f^{-1}}(\phi_f(\sigma))= f^{-1}\circ \phi_f(\sigma)\circ f = f^{-1}\circ f\circ \sigma\circ f^{-1}\circ f=\sigma,$$ so $\phi_{f^{-1}}\circ\phi_f=\operatorname{Id}_{\operatorname{Sym}(A)}$ and similarly $\phi_{f}\circ\phi_{f^{-1}}=\operatorname{Id}_{\operatorname{Sym}(B)}$.

Now if $|G|=n$, this just states that there *exists* a bijection $G\to \{1,\ldots,n\}$ of the underlying set of $G$ with the set of the first $n$ naturals. By waht we just saw, $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Sym}(\{1,\ldots,n\})=S_n$. Therefore, to show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$, it is sufficient to show that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(G)$: Any injective group homomorphism $G\hookrightarrow\operatorname{Sym}(G)$ produces an injective group homomorphism $G\hookrightarrow S_n$ via the isomorphism.

That being said, you essentially did the right thing: you considered left multiplication, i.e. for $a\in G$ the left multiplication by $a$, i.e. the map
$$\begin{align}\lambda_a\colon G&\to G\\
x&\mapsto ax\end{align} $$  We immediately verify that $\lambda_a(\lambda_b(x))=abx=\lambda_{ab}(x)$ (the law of associativity hides in here) so that $$\tag1\lambda_a\circ\lambda_b=\lambda_{ab}.$$ Moreover $\lambda_1$ is the identity map: $\lambda_1(x)=1x=x$). We conclude that $\lambda_a\circ\lambda_{a^{-1}}=\lambda_{a^{-1}}\circ \lambda_a=\lambda_1=\operatorname{Id}_G$, i.e. $\lambda_a$ is *bijective* with inverse $\lambda_{a^{-1}}$. Thus for each $a\in G$ we have an element $\lambda_a\in\operatorname{Sym}(G)$. Moreover, the map 
$$\begin{align}\lambda\colon G&\to \operatorname{Sym}G\\
a&\mapsto \lambda_a\end{align} $$ is a homomorphism because of $(1)$. This homomorphism has trivial kernel because $\lambda_a(1)=a\ne 1$ whenever $a\ne 1$. Thus we have our desired injective gorup homomorphism $\lambda\colon G\hookrightarrow \operatorname{Sym}(G)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer seems to be on the right way and in all the cases the answer of @Hagen von Eitzen seems is correct (for me at least :-) ).
But here an other more details proof with a slighlty different approach from an under graduate student that may help others. I will only treat the case where $(G;*)$ is finite (as it is in your question).

#### Question:

Let $G$ a finite group of cardinal $n$ . Show that $G$ is isomorph to a sub group of $S_n$ (the symmetric group).

#### Answer:

1-
First of all let's focus on the following function $ \sigma_a : G \rightarrow G$, with $a \in G$ defined as follow $ \forall x \in G, \sigma_a (x)=a*x $. This function is bijective, indeed:
*injectivity:* By absurd $ \exists x \neq y \Rightarrow a*x = \sigma_a (x)=\sigma_a (y) = a*y $ this means that as $G$ is a group $a$ as an inverse element $a^{-1} \in G$ and since we apply the same operation on both side the equality should be preserved. So  $a^{-1}* \sigma_a (x)=a^{-1}*a*x=x=a^{-1}*a*y=a^{-1}* \sigma_a (y) \Rightarrow x=y$ and this is incorrect!
*surjectivity:* $\forall y' \in G , \exists x'= a^{-1}*y' \in G$ (by def of $G$ that is a group) that verifies $\sigma_a (x')=a*a^{-1}*y=y$.
Now we can constat that not only $\sigma_a(x)$, but all the functions of the form of the $\sigma_a(x)$ are bijection and thus they belong to $(S_n; \circ )$ by def.

2-
We writte $H$ the set of all functions of the form of $\sigma_a(x)$.
In the specific case when $a=e$ (the neutral element) we get that $\sigma_e(x)=Id(x)$ (trivial to prove it).
$\forall \sigma_a(x), \sigma_b(x) \Rightarrow \sigma_a \circ \sigma_b^{-1}(x)=a*b^{-1}*x \in H $ because as $G$ is a group $a*b^{-1} \in G \Rightarrow \sigma_{a*b^{-1}}(x) \in H$ by def.
Hence $H$ is a sub group of $(S_n; \circ )$.

3-
Now let's define the following mapping $ \phi : G \rightarrow H \subseteq S_n$ as follow $\forall a \in G , \phi(a)=\sigma_a(x)$
*morphism:* $\phi(a*b)= \sigma_{a*b}(x)=a*b*x= \sigma_a [\sigma_b (x)] = \sigma_a \circ \sigma_b (x)= \phi(a) \circ \phi(b) $.
*injectivity:* By absurd $ \exists a \neq b \in G \Rightarrow \phi(a) = \sigma_a(x)=a*x=b*x=\sigma_b(x)=\phi(b)$ and as $G$ is agroup $ \exists x^{-1} \in G$ and the fact that we apply the same operation on both side of an equality we get $a*x*x^{-1}=a=b=b*x*x^{-1}$ and this is incorrect!
*surjectivity:* by def $\forall  \sigma_a(x) \in H \subseteq S_n, \exists a \in G \, s.t. \, \phi(a)=\sigma_a(x)$

Q.E.D.